# Eclipse Re-Open once closed project

Tags: eclipse, project, workspace

I am searching to find some answer my current actually presist problem.

I appreciate for any help and/or advice.

My problem is, I always delete projects once task finished. However, i delete project only Package Manager window and original project do exists in ADT work space.
When i want to re-open same project ecplise throws me error and says project is already in destination folder.

Could some one please tell me how can i re-open deleted projects?

Currently, i am copying entire project let's say to desktop and then re-import it into Workspace.
Is there any easy way to handle this?

The reason is that why i am deleting projects from my Project Manager because of too many projects are listing.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to copy the projects to another location. Just use 'Import Project' and specify the current workspace location. Eclipse will show you the deleted projects.

You can use 'Working Sets' to group your projects. You can tell Package Explorer to just show one working set or to show the working sets at the top level of the tree.

You can also have multiple workspaces and use 'File > Switch Workspace' to switch between them. I currently have 8 workspaces for different projects.

Comment: Thanks for help. I have just followed your instruction and it was worked. But i have tried Existing android Code Into Workspace option so many times but all i got was Cannot import project because it is already in Workspace. I am confuse now. Anyway, thanks for your help.